# Why does my EVENT.ACTIVE trigger twice?

Tags: actionscript-3

When I add an `EVENT.ACTIVATE` listener to my project, and then alt-tab away and back to my project it triggers twice.

**edit: shaunhusain and I seem to have found the cause of the problem, although without a solution. When running the standalone player version 11+ the event triggers 2x. When running standalone player version <11 or any version in the browser it triggers 1x. So it appears there may be a bug in recent versions of the flash player projector. I'm going to nail down the exact versions and report it to adobe and see what happens. Thanks to anyone who read this and tried to help!!**

I want it to fire every time I change focus, I just don't want it to fire *twice* every time I change focus.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong? What's the best way to prevent this behavior?

It seems like it would be a common question, but Google turned up nothing.

Code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, test);
        }

        private function test(e:Event):void
        {
            trace(e.target);
        }

    }

}
```

Actual result:

```
[object Stage]
[object Stage]
```

Desired result:

```
[object Stage]
```

It doesn't seem to make a difference whether I add the listener to the stage or anything else, the behavior is the same.

The same thing also happens with EVENT.DEACTIVATE. Others such as mouse up work fine.

My goal is to pause a game on `EVENT.DEACTIVATE` and unpause it on `EVENT.ACTIVATE`. The problem is that when the event fires twice, it calls the unpause function twice which has unwanted consequences.

Comment: Please add more information about the context you're building/running this in.  I just created an AS3 project in FlashBuilder, told it to run as an AIR application using the 4.6 SDK and can't reproduce, also tried a web application with the 4.5 SDK also can't reproduce, in both cases I get the expected result.

Comment: http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckActiveEventWeb/ http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckActiveEventWeb/srcview

Comment: That's strange indeed! Thanks for trying it. I'm using FlashDevelop 4.0.0 Beta R1978 with Flex 4.6.0. I don't have access to FlashBuilder but will ask on the flashdevelop forums. In the meantime if anybody has flashdevelop it would be awesome if you could try to repro the results.

Comment: hmm did you try the example I posted, I can try switching that to 4.6.0 SDK too, the thing is it shouldn't matter which IDE we're using since we have the compiler included in the SDK it should just be using that really (config provided by IDE though), some other thoughts: it works differently in Chrome vs Firefox, for me alt-tab back to Chrome drops me in the address bar, Alt-tab in firefox gives focus to the app... in chrome if I click the app it then gets focus, the event only happens once

Comment: I tried searching the whole SDK (4.6.0.23201B) and the only references to Event.ACTIVATE are adding/removing listeners but nothing dispatching it.  This leads me to believe 1 of 2 things might be true, 1 you're using a different flash player and the player itself is the problem, 2 one of these references in the framework is adding an extra listener for the same event (this appears to be possible in some of the Application classes, WindowApplication, ViewNavigatorApplication etc.)  If you have windows get Windows Grep if you're on *nix system use grep at the command line to see for yourself.

Comment: In flash builder you can go to the project properties (right click the project select properties) go to ActionScript or Flex Compiler depending on the project nature, then add this:"  -dump-config=someconfig.xml" that'll output the config being used by FlashBuilder into the bin-debug, do the same in FlashDevelop if possible, compare using a diff tool on Windows I use CSDiff (free) you may want to clean out the commented out lines to make diffing easier.

Comment: The compiled example you posted only fires 1 activate event. If I copy-paste it into flashdevelop and compile it myself, it fires 2 events. I downloaded the latest flashdevelop + flex and the same still thing happens. Now I'm downloading the FlashBuilder trial and will use your code + configuration to see if it makes a difference. After that I'll check grep. I am using flash player 11.2.202.235. Thanks so much for taking the time to look into this!

Comment: Hmm alrighty then... I have the same exact flash player version in Chrome 11.2.202.235, in Firefox I'm running 11.1.102.63 debug version.  So I guess that one can't be it maybe something in the config I suppose... posted it here http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckActiveEventWeb/someconfig.xml also posted one with the comments stripped http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckActiveEventWeb/someconfignocomment.xml

Comment: It gets even weirder. I just tried to compile your code using command line mxmlc and it still fires twice! I'm looking into grep but can't understand exactly what it is you want me to do. Am I searching the swf for event.activate? That can't be it because it doesn't turn up any results. Sorry, totally new to this! I'll try your configuration as soon as flash builder finishes downloading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12137/discussion-between-shaunhusain-and-wgfunstorm)

Comment: This is so strange! Using FlashBuilder 4.6 and vanilla configuration to build, it only fires 1x. BUT if I go to the FlashBuilder installation directory and use mxmlc from the exact same SDK used by FB to build it's back to firing 2x.

Comment: Have you tried stopPropgation? Maybe you are getting some funky bubbling going on.

Comment: we continued debugging in chat ultimately found it only happens in particular versions of the flash player, SDK didn't seem to be the problem ultimately, it works as expected in some cases and not in others, I asked that it be submitted to Adobe as a bug

Answer (score 1):

[ActionScript® 3.0 Reference for the Adobe® Flash® Platform says about this event:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html)

> Dispatched when the Flash Player or AIR application gains operating
>   system focus and becomes active. This event is a broadcast event,
>   which means that it is dispatched by all EventDispatcher objects with
>   a listener registered for this event. For more information about
>   broadcast events, see the DisplayObject class.

For me it looks like you want to prevent its designed behavior? I suppose it was designed to fire every time you change focus, or am I wrong? What do you want to accomplish? However this is an answer, so based on what you wrote - you can do a workaround by just removing a listener after he fired once:

```
    private function test(e:Event):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, test);

        trace(e.target);
    }
```

But I would recommend you to write something more about why are you using it and what want to accomplish if this is not satisfactory.

Comment: I want to pause a game on EVENT.DEACTIVATE, and then I want to resume it on EVENT.ACTIVATE.
  
After reading the documentation you quoted, I still don't understand why it fires twice. I want it to fire every time I change focus, I just don't want it to fire twice every time I changed focus. (Because then it calls the unpause() function twice which has unwanted effects).
  
If I remove the event listener as per your suggestion, then it doesn't fire again next time focus is gained.

Comment: What if you add it on DEACTIVATE?

Comment: Hmm this is indeed strange behavior, but looks consistent so you can just count events and ignore every second. Maybe someone else would be able to explain this.

Comment: Amy: I tried and it still fires a second time. Lukasz: I'm doing something like that for now but it feels like a dirty hack. Still, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in my AIR Mobile app.

To correct this issue, I've stored the last event name triggered for an Activate / Deactivate event. If it is attempted twice in a row, it just gets skipped with a `return;`

```
private static function onAppStateChanged(e:Event):void {
    if (_STATE == e.type) {
        return;
    }

    _STATE =    e.type;
    switch(_STATE) {
        case Event.ACTIVATE: whenActivated.dispatch(); break;
        case Event.DEACTIVATE: whenDeactivated.dispatch(); break;
    }
}
```

At first, the value of _STATE begins with **null**, so that should allow it to pass through the first time around.

I bind both **Event.ACTIVATE** and **Event.DEACTIVATE** to the same listener, `onAppStateChanged` in my App's initialization method, like so:

```
_STAGE.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onAppStateChanged);
_STAGE.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onAppStateChanged);
```

You can replace the **Switch-Statement** however you like, I just personally prefer using **Robert Penner's AS3Signals** ([GitHub](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals)) to broadcast the resume/suspend signal across the App.